# why does it give me "inf" and just same value when increasing floating value?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, floating-point

i was just testing maximum representation of float in c on mac pro. 
my program looks like this.
 And there are two types of program which increase by **multiply** and **adding**.
    #include

```
int main(void) {
    float a;
    a = 0;

    int index = 0;
    while(1) {
            a++;

            a = a +10000000000; // 1, **adding**  **resulting (1)**
            //a = a* 5;            2, **multiplying** **resulting (2)**

            printf("%f, %d\n",a,idex);

    }
}
```

**Resulting (1)**
It kept increasing till certain point where it just display the same result looks like this 288230376151711744.000000.

**Resulting (2)**
It didn't even show anything but **inf**

Could anyone explain why there is different situation happening ..?

Comment: Patricia beat me to it but i have to ask......why i++ you never even declare i as a variable. EDIT for that matter why a++ when you turn around and add 10000000000 to it

Comment: @RustyH haha im sorry to make you confused it was just kind of leftover from random stuff i don't even remember :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider an example.

Assume that a float number uses decimal representation, a mantissa has only one decimal digit, an exponent is in a range 0-2. So, all possible numbers are `0, 1, 2, ..., 9, 10, 20, ..., 90, 100, 200, ..., 900`. For example, 12 is not possible number because two decimal digit is required (1 and 2). 1000 is not possible value because too much zeroes are placed at the end (3 zeroes at the end, but maximum is 2). And we have special `inf` value to indicate overflow.

Let's try to increment and see what happens.

```
     1 + 1 =  2, (ok)
     2 + 1 =  3, (ok)
     ...
     8 + 1 =  9, (ok)
     9 + 1 = 10, (ok)
    10 + 1 = 11 -> 10, (not enough space to safe two digits, result is rounded to nearest possible number, that is 10)
    10 + 1 = 11 -> 10, (not enough space to safe two digits, result is rounded to nearest possible number, that is 10)
     ...
```

Let's try to multiply by 2 and see what happens:

```
       1 * 2 =    2, (ok)
       2 * 2 =    4, (ok)
       4 * 2 =    8, (ok)
       8 * 2 =   16 -> 20, (not enough space to safe two digits, result is rounded to nearest possible number, that is 20)
      20 * 2 =   40, (ok)
      40 * 2 =   80, (ok)
      80 * 2 =  160 -> 200, (not enough space to safe two digits, result is rounded to nearest possible number, that is 200)
     200 * 2 =  400, (ok)
     400 * 2 =  800, (ok)
     800 * 2 = 1600 -> inf, (overflow, the result is more that maximum value (900), so it is inf)
     inf * 2 =  inf, (ok)
     inf * 2 =  inf, (ok)
      ...
```

Answer (score 3):

For very large values of float, the gap between two consecutive floats is greater than 20000000000. Once you get to that point, adding 10000000000 cannot change the value.

The change caused by a multiplication scales with the value being multiplied, so the number goes on increasing until it overflows to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

A `float` only has a certain amount of memory storage. Obviously it can't represent every single possible real number.  In reality, there is a finite number of possible values that it can hold exactly.

You can find the largest of these with `FLT_MAX` (defined in `<float.h>`).  You'll probably find that the value you're getting "stuck" at is the biggest one such that adding `100000000000` does not get you to the next possible value after that.